# Qt - what is required for a QTDIR to be considered valid by build tools?

Tags: qt, qt4

A client of mine has built Qt against VS2005.  They are now wanting to put this into source control, but they don't want anything they don't need.

What's the proper way to remove temporary stuff like the "tmp" directories, without deleting output libs/DLLs or invalidating the tree for use as a QTDIR target?

If there's no prebuilt way to do it, what files are safe to delete?  (Makefile.Release, VC80.pdb, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any proper way.

You can delete these things at least (copy-pasted from a script used for binary packaging):

```
Makefile
Makefile.Release
Makefile.Debug
*.sln
*.vcproj
*.ib_pdb_index
./tests/
**/tmp/obj/
**/tmp/moc/
**/tmp/rcc/
./.git/
```

Comment: I guess this is close enough for now.  I was hoping for something a little more... official.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum at compile time you would need \include and \lib.  And maybe keep \plugins for runtime.

Comment: Sorry, this is not particularly useful.  To be a valid QTDIR target, some bits of the src tree are required...  but I'm not sure which.